# After login no personal prices showing

Tags: price, catalog-price-rules

After login, no personal prices are showing.
Site is testshop.etkserver.nl
Also, the price in the product tile is gone. Not sure if those two issues are related.
I have been working on other things, but I cannot think of anything I did that might have caused the prices to disappear.

This is a screenshots of a part of a page with product tiles before login:
[image: Before login]

And this is after login:
[image: After login]

The listing on the product detailpage does not show discounted prices either, see:
[image: no discount prices on product page]

It used to work.
I hope someone can tell me where to look. Or what to do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The file prints the box price

```
<div class="price-box">...</div>
```

is \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml

So, try to insert a var_dump() in the top to see if it prints somethings when you are logged.

If you don't see anything, maybe this file in not included in the layout and maybe you have to check .xml layout file.

NOTE: if you installed a 3rd party theme, try to contact theme developers.

Comment: Thank you very much... I included <?php var_dump($_finalPrice);?> in price.phtml and see NULL appearing above the price in the last screendump above. So, not sure if there is anything else I can do. I posted the question to the forum of my theme, but no answer until now. I suppose you don't have any other suggestion?

Comment: have you inserted var_dump() after $_finalPrice declaration?
Anyway, if you see something vardumped when logged in it means that magento use this file, it is good.
Now you have to debug ~435ln where you see class="minimal-price" and understand why magento doesn't print anything.

Comment: I solved half of the problem. "View on productpage" was set to "No" for the attribute "Special price". Changing that to Yes solved the last issue. 
However, I have not been able to solve first issue.